# Set 2 divs in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make 2 divs be in one row. Here is example : https://jsfiddle.net/cu0L469f/

But always i get each of it in separate row or they are as joined in one row.

```
<form id="postJob" class="login-form">
            <div class="bro">
                <div class="left4">
<div class="row-fluid clearfix">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 pull-left">
                            <label class="text_7">Full Address</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fromAddress" name="fromAddress" class="input" maxlength="1000"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left">
                            <label class="text_7">Postcode</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fromAddressPostCode" name="fromAddressPostCode" class="input" maxlength="8"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try removing the `width:40%;` from your left4 class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using only `col-lg` class and possible you seeing in small screen, you should also add `col-md` and `col-sm` and `col-xs` according to your need.

Go with link to see **[more details](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

```
<form id="postJob" class="login-form">
  <div class="bro">
    <div class="left4">
      <div class="row-fluid clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <label class="text_7">Full Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="fromAddress" name="fromAddress" class="input" maxlength="1000"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <label class="text_7">Postcode</label>
          <input type="text" id="fromAddressPostCode" name="fromAddressPostCode" class="input" maxlength="8"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```